# Pegar primeira letra de cada palavra

Tags: php

Estou usando o seguinte código para capturar a primeira letra de cada palavra. Como eu posso acrescentar mais uma regra no `preg_split` para ignorar palavras como: da, do, das, dos, de?

```
$nome = preg_split("/[\s,_-]+/", $loja->nome);
$iniciais = "";
foreach($nome as $n)
   $iniciais .= $n[0];

echo $iniciais;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$nome = preg_split("/((de|da|do|dos|das)?)[\s,_-]+/", "A C Loja do Supermercado");
$iniciais = "";
foreach($nome as $n)
{
    if (strlen($n) > 0)
    {
       $iniciais .= $n[0];
    }
}

echo $iniciais;
```

[*Verifique o exemplo ONLINE Ideone*](https://ideone.com/qKeWmj)

<sub>***Referencia:*** [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php)</sub>

Comment: Não funcionou. Não acho q seja esse o problema, já que o código sem remover essas palavras está funcionando, mas o código está dentro de um foreach, pq preciso pegar as iniciais de todas lojas do sistema.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Qual foi o problema de não funcionar? o que aconteceu, porque, eu gerei inclusive uma página de teste e funcionou! agora por exemplo fiz um ajuste para ficar sem o problema de campos vazios  verifique! e me avise e se tiver problemas relate o problema!

Comment: Agora funcionou perfeitamente! Valeu!